# For Colocation should your IIS server be left on and logged in for services to work?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have no idea about servers or colocation.

But essentially when my IIS server is colocated does the server just need to be switched on to "work" or does a user (for e.g. Admin) need to be logged into windows for then IIS and other services to work?

This is such a newb question I understand that but I'm just trying to understand here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services like IIS are non-interactive (in fact, all services are non-interactive on Windows 2008), and run as a service user.  This user may be a "regular" user, or special-purpose, but the user does not need to be logged in to a terminal session for IIS to be running.

Comment: Brilliant, so as long as the machine is on IIS, Sql Server and other services should run fine. Thank you

Comment: Yup, that's correct (assuming of course that they are properly installed/configured).  If this answer has been helpful, please feel free to accept it by hitting the checkmark on the lefthand side.

Comment: Very helpful and accepted.

Answer (score -2):

They are the same as any other system you use, local or otherwise, The exact same rules apply.

*So for the switched on part of your questions, what normally happens when a system is turned off? I think that will answer your query for you.*

Comment: I think you missed the point.

Comment: -1, completely missed the point. He's not asking if services are available if the server is off, he wants to know whether IIS is available *with no user logged on*.